# Why didn't Rudin use the theorem that every locally compact Hausdorff space is regular?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

In Rudin's Book there is a  theorem given below

> Here is the outline of  the theorem

> **Theorem 2.7:**  *Suppose $U$ is open in a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$,  $K \subset U$, and $K$ is compact.  Then there is an open set $V$ with compact closure such that*$$K \subset V \subset \overline{V} \subset U.$$

> Proof:

> Let $C$ be the complement of $U$.  By theorem 2.5, to each $p \in C$ there exists an open set $W_p$ that contains $K$ and $p \notin \overline{W_p}$.  Thus $\{ C \cap \overline{G} \cap \overline{W_p} \}$, where $p$ ranges over $C$, is a collection of compact sets with an empty intersection.   Then by theorem 2.6 there are points $p_1, \ldots, p_n \in C$ such that $$C \cap \overline{G} \cap \overline{W_{p_1}} \cap \ldots \cap \overline{W_{p_n}} = \emptyset.$$

Then we define $V = G \cap W_{p_1} \cap \ldots \cap W_{p_n}$ and we are done, $V$ satisfies the conclusion of the theorem.

Here   *Rudin* proof is difficult to understand

**My confusion** : why didn't *Rudin* use the theorem that every locally compact Hausdorff space is regular?

From this theorem we can easily prove  the theorem $2.7$

Let $K \subseteq X$ be compact, and let $U \subseteq X$ be open such that $K \subseteq U$.  Then since $U$ is open, $U^{c}$ is closed.  But $U^{c}$ closed and $K$ compact implies we can find $W_p, V$ open such that $K \subseteq W_p$ and $U^{c} \subseteq V$ with $W_p \cap V = \emptyset$ (this is because locally compact Hausdorff topological spaces are regular).  But if $U^{c} \subseteq W_p$, then $V^{c} \subseteq W_p$.

Since $W_p$ is open, $W_p^{c}$ is closed.  Also, $W_p \cap V = \emptyset \implies V \subseteq W_p^{c}$.  Since $W_p^{c}$ is closed, we have the closure of $V$, $\overline{V}$, is contained in $W_p^{c}$.  So, we have $K \subseteq V \subseteq \overline{V} \subseteq U$.  We can assume $\overline{V}$ is compact, and so we are done

Comment: I thought that this theorem is needed to prove that every LCH space is regular? I am not sure though.

Comment: "We can assume $\overline{V}$ is compact", why? You're skipping a step somewhere.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn No, it's not needed: just consider $\alpha X$ which is normal, so regular, and regularity is hereditary. The result itself doesn't need regularity (though it does imply it): just separate $K$ and $U^c$ in $\alpha X$ and relativise.

Comment: Rudin's Book? Do you think that there is only one mathematician named Rudin, and that Rudin only wrote one book?

Comment: @bof    no , i don't think like that  ....but Rudin is one of the best author in analysis book..